# Преобразование числа в обратно отсортированный массив

Tags: javascript

Мой код не проходит тесты, что я не так делаю? заодно помогите улучшить сам код ?

```
 function digitize(n) {
 var str = String(n);
 var str1 = str.split('').reverse();
 return str1;
}

digitize(35231);
```

> Необходимо получить: '[1, 3, 2, 5, 3]', вместо этого получаю: '[\'1\', \'3\', \'2\', \'5\', \'3\']

Comment: но твой код **не** сортирует массив

Comment: @Grundy а я думал сортирует `r str1 = str.split('').reverse();` почему нет , не подскажешь?

Comment: потому что при сортировке у тебя было бы: `1,2,3,3,5`

Comment: но ведь я имел ввиду под сортировкой, гораздо шире короче, не только в контексте js/ Поэтому мог запутать вас. проше было сказать сказать нужно вернуть массив, с обратным порядком элементов.

Comment: тут сортировка в любом виде **отсортировала** бы, а тут ты просто _развернул_ массив.

Comment: @Grundy из-за этого у меня получились эти символы `'[\'1\', \'3\', \'2\', \'5\', \'3\']`

Comment: нет, символы у тебя получились, потому что ты делил **строку** на символы, получил массив символов и вернул его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо сделать приведение типов:

```js
var arr = digitize(35231);
console.log(arr);

function digitize(n) {
  n = String(n).split('').reverse().map(Number);
  return n;
}
```

Источник: [map](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration#map), глобальный объект [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Answer (score 2):

В качестве альтернативы связке [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) можно воспользоваться методом [reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)

```js
function digitize(n) {
  return [].reduceRight.call(String(n), (acc, char) => acc.concat(+char), []);
}

console.log(digitize(35231));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо ещё преобразовать все символы в `int`
Вот рабочий вариант:

```
function digitize(n) {
 var str = String(n);
 var str1 = str.split('').reverse();
 for(var i=0; i<str1.length;i++) str1[i] = parseInt(str1[i], 10);
 return str1;
}

digitize(35231);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так сделать

```js
var arr = digitize(35231);
console.log(arr);

function digitize(n) {
  n = String(n).split('').reverse().join();
  return n;
}
```

Comment: судя по вопросу - возвращаемое значение должно быть массивом цифр, а не строкой

Comment: @Grundy судя по предполагаемому ответу - как раз строкой: Необходимо получить: '[1, 3, 2, 5, 3]'

Comment: но даже в этом случае - пример выводит совсем другое: `1,3,2,5,3` вместо `'[1, 3, 2, 5, 3]'`

Comment: @Grundy тут да, косяк. Но входных данных никто не предоставил)

Comment: @Grundy а ещё, он скорее всего поменяет местами квадратные скобки, если передать строку.

Comment: входные данные есть: это число. А вот с выходными действительно есть легкое недопонимание. Но судя по вопросу _**Преобразование числа** в обратно отсортированный **массив**_ - нужен все-таки массив, а не что-то другое

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение в одну строку.

`let digitize = (n) => n = String(n).split("").reverse().map(Number);`

Comment: чем этот способ отличается от уже представленных?

Answer (score -1):

```
function digitize(n){
  return (n + '').split('').map(Number).reverse();
}
```

Comment: чем оно современнее?

Comment: согласен ничем. но лучше первоночального варианта поэтому запостил

Comment: а чем лучше первоначального варианта?

Comment: Будьте вежливее. Выражения, подобные приведенным вами, неприемлемы на Stack Overflow. Пожалуйста, добавьте комментарий к приведенному вами коду. В текущем виде, с большой вероятностью, он будет непонятен коллегам, пришедшим на вопрос из поисковика.